# What are the limits to parallel shift registers in electronics (in comparison to optics)?

Tags: digital-logic, shift-register, optics, optical

[Brackenbury and Mason in 1988](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0022-3727/21/10S/044) said, on comparing parallel shift registers in electronic and optical computing:

> When implementing such a scheme in electronics, the shift length is usually limited to modest lengths by the width of the largest multiplexer available in a particular logic family (often eight-to-one) and by the density of the wiring around the multiplexers. An optical approach does not have these limitations and is representative of a function which it is advantageous to implement optically rather than electronically.

Is there anywhere I can look to quantify these limits, particularly in the density of the multiplexer wiring? Some Google searches haven't yielded anything as this is not my area of expertise so I haven't been very specific with the searches.

Comment: The article is behind a paywall. As for mux, you are limited by your FPGA. Modern designs do not use discrete logic devices for anything more complex than glue logic, they use either FPGA or ASICs.

Comment: 32 years have passed since that paper was published. We are still using electronics to enthuse about how good optics will be someday. I think from this we can infer the relative severity of the limitations of optics versus electronics.

Comment: @LiorBilia, that said, if your design needs this function (shift register able to shift by arbitrary number of steps per cycle) it's going to be a relatively "expensive" block in an FPGA. (On the other hand I expect the space needed to implement it in optics is comparable to the whole die area of the FPGA)

Comment: @TimWescott Of course, but I have to make a gesture at giving optics a fair chance in the argument. For this, I am tracing back through research in the 60s-80s when people still thought it might have a chance. Brackenbury and Mason also acknowledge that the liquid crystal technology available at the time could not facilitate an all-optical alternative to electronic computing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a shifter that shifts an arbitrary number of bits using just 2:1 multiplexers. This structure is commonly called a **barrel shifter**, and it is how modern microcontrollers (e.g. ARM Cortex-M) can shift up to 32 bits in a single clock cycle. For an \$N\$ bit shifter you need \$N \times \log_2(N)\$ 2:1 multiplexers.

But you left out most the important information needed to compare optical and electronic methods. How many bits are really necessary? How fast does it need to be? How much silicon can you devote to it? Without the answers to those questions it is impossible to make a meaningful comparison.